# firebase get least time taken returning null value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Hey I am trying to find the least time taken by a user by the following code but for some reason it says that the value of timeTaken is null. 
When I logged in it shows the incorrect user's  time taken so what could be the probable solution.

```
    private void leastTimeTaken() {
    final DatabaseReference databaseReference1 = firebaseUrl.child("users");
    final Query query = databaseReference1.orderByChild("timeTaken").limitToFirst(1);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot userAnswerSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (userAnswerSnapshot.child("questions").child(imagename).hasChild("timeTaken")) {
                    long a = userAnswerSnapshot.child("questions").child(imagename).child("timeTaken").getValue(Long.class);
                    DatabaseReference userPuzzleDetails = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid).child("questions").child(imagename);
                    userPuzzleDetails.child("leastTime").setValue(a);
                }

                query.removeEventListener(this);
                databaseReference1.removeEventListener(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the value of imagename

Comment: imagename is the value 9829 values @SaqibAhmed

Comment: I think 9829 is not present in questions, thats whay returing null, try using complete value between  982906 and 982920

Comment: correction 982920 is the value. When I am trying to get the value of userAnswerSnapshot it only shows tempTime and tempScore and not any other WHat could be the reason @SaqibAhmed